# How to save multiple files in this Fortran code? The code works with up to 10 file numbers but after that it overwrites the existing files

Tags: fortran

The following program aims to generate multiple files for each iteration. However, it works perfectly fine for 10 file numbers. It overwrites the existing files when the timestep(file number) is taken more than 10 as here it is 15.

```
program iteration
implicit none

integer ( kind = 8 ), parameter :: timestep = 15
integer ( kind = 4 ) divisor(timestep)
character ( len = 80 ) filename(timestep)
integer ( kind = 4 ) fileunit(timestep)
character ( len = 80 ) template
integer ( kind = 4 ) i

do i = 1,timestep        
    divisor(i) = 0 + i 
end do

template = 'divisor0.txt'

do i = 1, timestep
    call filename_inc ( template )
    filename(i) = template
end do

do i = 1, timestep
    fileunit(i) = i
    open ( unit = fileunit(i), file = filename(i), status = 'replace' )
    write ( fileunit(i), '(a,i2)' ) 'Sum of ', divisor(i)
end do

do i = 1, timestep
    close ( unit = fileunit(i) )
end do

end program iteration
```

The reference to the code is [1]
[1]: [https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f_src/files_multiple/files_multiple.f90](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/%7Ejburkardt/f_src/files_multiple/files_multiple.f90)

The following subroutine is also taken from the same source.

```
subroutine filename_inc ( filename )
implicit none

character c
integer ( kind = 4 ) change
integer ( kind = 4 ) digit
character ( len = * ) filename
integer ( kind = 4 ) i
integer ( kind = 4 ) lens

lens = len_trim ( filename )

if ( lens <= 0 ) then
    write ( *, '(a)' ) ' '
    write ( *, '(a)' ) 'FILENAME_INC - Fatal error!'
    write ( *, '(a)' ) '  The input string is empty.'
    stop
end if

change = 0

do i = lens, 1, -1
    
    c = filename(i:i)
    
    if ( lge ( c, '0' ) .and. lle ( c, '9' ) ) then
        
        change = change + 1
        
        digit = ichar ( c ) - 48
        digit = digit + 1
        
        if ( digit == 10 ) then
            digit = 0
        end if
        
        c = char ( digit + 48 )
        
        filename(i:i) = c
        
        if ( c /= '0' ) then
            return
        end if
        
    end if
    
end do
!
!  No digits were found.  Return blank.
!
if ( change == 0 ) then
    filename = ' '
    return
end if

return
end

subroutine get_unit ( iunit )
  implicit none

  integer ( kind = 4 ) i
  integer ( kind = 4 ) ios
  integer ( kind = 4 ) iunit
  logical lopen

  iunit = 0

  do i = 1, 200    !99

if ( i /= 5 .and. i /= 6 .and. i /= 9 ) then

  inquire ( unit = i, opened = lopen, iostat = ios )

  if ( ios == 0 ) then
    if ( .not. lopen ) then
      iunit = i
      return
    end if
  end if

end if

end do

return
end
```

Comment: If you have `template = 'divisor0.txt'` then wouldn't ten files make sense as a limit?

Comment: Once you have fixed the template, in filename_inc, when the number reaches 10, the digit is correctly set back to zero but the tens are not incremented.

Comment: So how to save more than 10 files. Where to bring change here? @francescalus

Comment: Isn't this just a variation on OP's previous question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63662879/how-to-open-and-save-iterations-in-new-files-in-fortran - ?

Comment: Which no one could answer and solved and still it is not @HighPerformanceMark

Comment: If you want to have files 0-14 then you'll need two digits, so `template = 'divisor00.txt'` would be my naive attempt.  I haven't thought about the code beyond that, but please try it and see if it's sufficient.

Comment: It was closed for being a duplicate of an earlier question which does have answers - I don't understand why you haven't been able to use those to solve your problem.

Comment: It works fine with template= 'divisor00.txt' till two-digit files. But template = 'divisor000.txt' does not work for three-digit files. I look for the reason but in vain.

Comment: @Shahid In that case you have to show that  code for three digits and show what "does not work", show the specific error messages etc.

Answer (score 0):

Its not 100% clear what you mean by not working(My rep doesn't allow me to make comments yet so I'm including this as an answer) The reference code looks to me like it works as designed. Would adding the following to your code make it work?

Add to definitions

```
character ( len = 80 ) fmtstr
```

Replace code for initializing template

```
! template = 'divisor00.txt'
write(fmtstr, '("(a,i",i0,".",i0,",a)")') cieling(log10(real(timestep))), ceiling(log10(real(timestep)))
write(template, fmtstr) 'divisor',0,'.txt'
```

This would make the template file correct for any size timestep parameter(haven't tested >10^10).  Note that for timesteps that are 10^int the last timestep will be divisor00.txt.
One other note - this code runs the risk of clashing with the Predefined Unit numbers like 1,5,6 depending on your compiler.

If this doesn't solve your issue give more detail on what "doesn't work' means

The reason I think the reference code works as designed is that this test rig seems to give valid results

```
Program TestFileInc
character (len=20) InpFileName, OutFileName

call test_filename_inc('a7to12.txt')
call test_filename_inc('a7to99.txt')
call test_filename_inc('a9to99.txt')
call test_filename_inc('cat.txt')
! call test_filename_inc(' ')
! call test_filename_inc('')
call test_filename_inc('aonly5.txt')
call test_filename_inc('3.txt')
call test_filename_inc('txt.3')
call test_filename_inc('3')
call test_filename_inc('9')
call test_filename_inc('19')
call test_filename_inc('99')

InpFileName = 'divisor00.txt'
OutFileName = InpFileName
Write(*,*) InpFileName, '                         ***From 1-101'
Do i = 1, 101
  call filename_inc(OutFileName)
  Write(*,*) InpFileName, '        ',OutFileName
End Do

InpFileName = 'divisor000.txt'
OutFileName = InpFileName
Write(*,*) InpFileName, '                         ***From 1-1001'
Do i = 1, 1001
  call filename_inc(OutFileName)
  Write(*,*) InpFileName, '        ',OutFileName
End Do

End Program

subroutine test_filename_inc(filename)
character (len=*) filename
character (len=20) OutFileName, NewOutFileName


OutFileName =filename
Call filename_inc(OutFileName)
Write(*,*) filename, '        ',OutFileName
! Call fileName_inc_new(NewOutFileName)
! Write(*,*) filename, OutFileName, NewOutFileName

end subroutine
```

Comment: Sorry for the ugliness of the test rig code, was in a hurry

Comment: Note, you should always include the text of the error msg in your question. My code will fix your problem. But you need to understand that your code will redirect your std input and std output(which are preconnected to UNIT=5 and UNIT=6) to the divisor5.txt and divisor6.txt files so write(*,*) etc will not work as expected.  I recommend you offset your fileunit by 10 so use fileunit(i) = i +10 or change all of you loops to do i = 10, timestep + 10(and resize arrays to (timeset +10)

Comment: It is working now. I needed to change a few things there. First, I added the subroutine :subroutine get_unit ( iunit ) and then changed the divisor000.txt to get the three-digit output files.